# How do I get Puppet exec resource to determine if a Chocolatey source has already been disabled using the unless clause with the PowerShell provider?

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet, chocolatey

The `exec` runs every time. When I manually execute the `unless` clause, it exits 0.

```
exec { 'disablepublicchocolatey':
    command => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source disable -n=chocolatey",
    unless  => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source list | findstr -i 'chocolatey [Disabled]'",
    require => Exec['chocolatelyinstall'],
    provider => powershell,
}
```

Is there a better way to check if a Chocolatey source is already disabled? Is the string matching not robust enough?

---

FYI, Windows 7 x64.

Comment: The `unless` should always run. That's how it knows to not run `command`.. unless I'm not reading your question properly.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is the command always runs - the unless seems to never exit 0 so puppet knows NOT to run the command, even if it seems to do the "right" thing on the command line.

Comment: Can you run puppet with `-debug` and provide the full output? Possibly include `logoutput => true,` in your `exec` resource for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work if you use the regular exec provider.

```
exec { 'disablepublicchocolatey':
  command => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source disable -n=chocolatey",
  unless  => "cmd /c C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source list | findstr -i 'chocolatey [Disabled]'",
  require => Exec['chocolateyinstall'],
}
```

If you use PowerShell, you should assign your output to a variable and then query whether the output string contains what you are looking for:

```
$sourceOutput = choco.exe source list
$sourceOutput.Contains('chocolatey [Disabled]')
```

#### UPDATE for the PowerShell One Liner

You can separate statements with semi-colon, so this should provide what you need

```
exec { 'disable_public_chocolatey':
    command => "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe source disable -n=chocolatey",
    unless  => "\$sourceOutput = choco.exe source list; if (\$sourceOutput.Contains('chocolatey [Disabled]')) {exit 0} else {exit 1}",
    require => Exec['chocolatelyinstall'],
    provider => powershell,
}
```

#### Update 2 - Chocolatey provider adding configuration support

This doesn't really help you right now, but something being added in the future is https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3428

The gist is:

```
chocolatey::source {'name':
  location => '',
  ensure => present|absent,
  enabled => true|false,
  username => '',
  password => '',
}
```

Which should lower the amount of work in configuring choco appropriately.

#### Update 3 - Chocolatey provider configuration support

I mentioned in Update 2 that the provider would add configuration support. The sources bit is in PR mode and working - https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey/pull/79/files

#### Update 4 - Chocolatey provider - chocolateysource

Back in 2016ish, the Chocolatey module was moved under Puppet supported (puppetlabs/chocolatey) and config settings, features, and sources support were added. Find that at https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/chocolatey

Comment: I started with the regular provider, but it did the same thing.

Comment: Interesting. Let me suggest something else. :)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, except for my second case where I want to have a parameter in Puppet, which needs to be interpolated like $choco_repo_name but not have puppet fail because it obviously doesn't know what $sourceOutput is...

Comment: And the quoting may also not work well, as it still doesn't seem to do what  I'd expect...

Comment: Have I mentioned that in the future the provider will have support for sources? https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3428

Comment: I would love to have sources in the provider. Sadly, "in the future" doesn't help me today :P...

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do this with a template file for the config file. Much easier!

Comment: @jmp242 that's good! I will caution to continue to check how that changes with future choco versions.